# How to display each individual word of a string?

Tags: string, matlab, loops

How can I display each individual word of a string? I wrote a loop, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html), which by default splits by white-space:

```
>> str='How to display each individual word of a string';
>> words = strsplit(str);
>> words.' %' each word is in a cell (words{1} is first word)
ans = 
    'How'
    'to'
    'display'
    'each'
    'individual'
    'word'
    'of'
    'a'
    'string'
```

Or if you prefer [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html), you can apply the rarely-used [`'split'` keyword](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btqcpjk-4):

```
>> words = regexp(str,'[\s]','split')
words = 
    'How'    'to'    'display'    'each'    'individual'    'word'    'of'    'a'    'string'
```

Comment: The strsplit function doesn't work

Comment: It's in newer MATLAB versions.  Use the `regexp` solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `strsplit` function.

```
str = 'How to display each individual word of a string';
splitWords = strsplit(str)
```

Comment: Thank you! And how can I display just a part of the string? For example only the words: How to display (each on a separate line) and not the rest of the string.

Comment: splitWords is a cell array. so you can use splitWords{1} to display the first word and so on.