# How to display each individual word of a string in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab

How to display each individual word of a string in MATLAB version R2012a? The function strsplit doesn't work in this version. For example 'Hello, here I am'. I want to display every word on a single line.

Comment: The function `strsplit` (equivalent) is available on [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21710-string-toolkits/content/strings/strsplit.m) for use in old versions of Matlab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display each individual word of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612308/how-to-display-each-individual-word-of-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

Each word in a single line means replacing each blank with a new line:

```
strrep(s,' ',sprintf('\n'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) with the `'split'` option:

```
>> str = 'Hello, here I am';
>> words = regexp(str, '\s+', 'split').'

words = 

    'Hello,'
    'here'
    'I'
    'am'
```

Change `'\s+'` to a more elaborate pattern if needed.

Comment: Thank you! And what if I just want to show a part of the string? For example just the words 'hello' and 'here'?

Comment: `words(1:2)` for first to second word.